# CrashLoopBackOff : Back-off restarting failed container

Tags: kubernetes, containers, vagrant, devops, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to debug my pod throwing CrashLoopBackOff error. When I run decribe command, I found that `Back-off restarting failed container` is the error. I excuted the logs for the failing pod and I got the below data.

```
vagrant@master:~> kubectl logs pod_name
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error

vagrant@master:/vagrant> kubectl logs -p  pod_name
unable to retrieve container logs for containerd://db0f2dbd549676d8bf1026e5757ff45847c62152049b36037263f81915e948eavagrant
```

Why I am not able to execute the logs command?

More details:

[image]

yaml file is as follows

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    service: udaconnect-app
  name: udaconnect-app
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "3000"
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
    nodePort: 30000
  selector:
    service: udaconnect-app
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    service: udaconnect-app
  name: udaconnect-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: udaconnect-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: udaconnect-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: udacity/nd064-udaconnect-app:latest
        name: udaconnect-app
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "64m"
          limits:
            memory: "256Mi"
            cpu: "256m"
      restartPolicy: Always
```

My vagrant file

```
default_box = "opensuse/Leap-15.2.x86_64" 
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.define "master" do |master|
    master.vm.box = default_box
    master.vm.hostname = "master"
    master.vm.network 'private_network', ip: "192.168.0.200",  virtualbox__intnet: true
    master.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2222, id: "ssh", disabled: true
    master.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2000 # Master Node SSH
    master.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6443, host: 6443 # API Access
    for p in 30000..30100 # expose NodePort IP's
      master.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: p, host: p, protocol: "tcp"
      end
    master.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.memory = "3072"
      v.name = "master"
      end
    master.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
      sudo zypper refresh
      sudo zypper --non-interactive install bzip2
      sudo zypper --non-interactive install etcd
      sudo zypper --non-interactive install apparmor-parser
      curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -
    SHELL
  end

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.memory = "4096"
      vb.cpus = 4
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the architecture of machine Kubernetes runs on? Similar error occurs when trying to run containers built for AMD64 on ARM64 devices.

Comment: To repeat what the previous comment said in a different way, I think you WERE able to execute the logs command, and "exec user process caused: exec format error" is what was in the log.

Comment: This kind of error is mostly because of different (mismatch) of image arch & host arch. Try to run `docker inspect <image>`, your image is amd64 arch, most probably your host or vagrant arch is not amd64.

Comment: I have added my vagrant file for your reference. So does that mean, I should change my box?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Yes...

Comment: @arunprakashpj, have you resolved your issue?

Comment: @Bazhikov I am running everything inside my vagrant. The issue is yet to get resolved.

Comment: @Riwen Are you talking about the processor I use ?

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing the comments: `CrashLoopBackOff` error occurs, when there is a mismatch of AMD64 and ARM64 devices. According to your docker image `udacity/nd064-udaconnect-app`, we can see that it's [AMD64 arch](https://hub.docker.com/r/udacity/nd064-udaconnect-app/tags) and your box `opensuse/Leap-15.2.x86_64` is [ARM64 arch](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:AArch64).

Hence, you have to change either your docker image, or the box in order to resolve this issue.

Comment: This solved my issue. I had ARM processor in my raspberry-pi cluster and I was using AMD images.